# How is it possible to compare powers of normality tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, model-comparison

The famous paper [1] compares the power of several normality
tests. Regardless of its result, my immediate question is, **"How
is that even possible?"**

Well, the definition of *power* in this case is the probability
of rejecting the null hypothesis

> H_0: the underlying distribution is a singly variated normal
> distribution

**assuming $H_{0}$ to be wrong.** However, $H_{0}$ is so
restrictive among all continuous singly variated distributions.
It would be very difficult to provide a right judgement because in order to prove that a test is certainly more powerful
than another, one needs to argue across all singly variated
non-normal distributions!

And indeed, the approach [1] takes, is (quoted):

> Ten thousand samples of various sample size were generated from each
> of the given alternative symmetric and asymmetric distributions.

They simply picked some of their favorite
non-normal distributions. Of course, this would give us some
ranking among the powers of the tests. However, isn't that
misleading? For other types of non-normal distributions, perhaps
the least powerful one would become the most powerful.

#### reference

- [1] Power comparisons of Shapiro-Wilk, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Lilliefors and Anderson-Darling tests - Nornadiah Mohd Razali

Comment: In some cases you may be correct.  But there are two features of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which make it conservative (the conditional probability of a Type I error is often less than $\alpha$) and thus underpowered: (a) it assumes the mean and variance are known when they are typically estimated from the data and (b) it concentrates on the maximum deviation and ignores the rest of the distribution of the deviations.

Comment: The power of the tests can only be compared in defined circumstances, as you already suppose. What you need to know about normality tests in the context of significance testing is that they typically do not have sufficient power to be useful with the small sample sizes where, for example, a t-test would be adversely affected by modest deviations from normality. When you have a large enough sample for the normality test to be well-powered the significance test is unaffected by non-normality unless it is so extreme that even an eyeball normality test will work well enough.